# Should error codes be used as tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

If a question contains a tag like [80073cf9](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/80073cf9) should the error code also be used as a tag to be able to browse all questions related to that error code?

Answer (score 6):

I don't think it is a good practice.

In general questions about an specific error probably end up in just one question so no need for a tag.

The problem is that the "Community" bot is creating tags with things in the title and I'm noob enough to can't find where to delete it.

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree, a search will quickly turn up all related examples and tagging does not add an additional context.

Comment: I didn't realise that the community bot created tags?

Comment: @RowlandShaw Well, it appeared in the mod review because someone added a tag description. But there was shown that was created by the community "something"

Comment: Community only creates blank tag wikis - it doesn't edit questions to create tags themselves, as I understood it

Comment: That's correct, the Community bot only creates blank tag wikis and excerpts as necessary. Specifically, when the first editor doesn't have tag wiki editing privileges and the edit has to go through peer review, because the review page needs to show both the "before" and "after" revisions. Anyway, I think the [80073cf9] tag should be deleted.